# I can not play mp3 file using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, mp3, avfoundation, core-audio

I want to play mp3 file placed in resources as code is given below,

```
NSString *st=@"alarm_1.mp3";
NSLog(st);
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:st]; 

AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];

//AVAudioPlayer *click1=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"alarm_1.mp3"]];

[click prepareToPlay];
[click play];
[click release];
```

but unfortunately i cant hear the sound 
please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think your file name is right.  Try this syntax:

```
    NSURL *clickURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/alarm_1.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];  
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:clickURL error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem due to ARC. Instead of defining the AVAudioPlayer in the same method you are using it, you should should have an instance variable somewhere else, such as the UIViewController. This way ARC doesn't auto release this object and audio can play.

Comment: Yes, the key here is that for play "sound is played asynchronously."

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/alarm_1.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

[audioPlayer play];
```

This is answer

Comment: Why did you bother creating an NSError* and passing it to the AudioPlayer initialiser, and then not bother to check the return value and deal with the error?